# Greatest Integer Function and graphing

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denote the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ and let $n^3 + 3n = 6 (\lfloor n \rfloor ^2) + \frac {478}{27}$, then solve for $n$?
Using plot function in wolfarm gives me different solution when I try to solve analytically. Also when I try to impose condition that fractional part is less than 1 but greater than equal to zero, the equation turns out to be unwieldy for me. What is the right way to tackle this problem?

Comment: What *were* the solutions you obtained in the two cases?

Comment: First route gives me n = 5.333 but I am unable to solve analytically. That's what I am trying to figure out,

Comment: I haven't found a nice way to do this, but are you familiar with the general formula for the solutions of a cubic? If you set $n := n + k$ where $0 \le k < 1$ then you get something that can at least be solved, though it's very messy.

Comment: I have already tried your suggested route already but like you I am ending up in a messy form which is what I am looking for help at?

Comment: Any hint or suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$f(x) = x^3 - 6 \lfloor x \rfloor^2 + 3x - 478/27 \tag{A}$$

Then we are trying to solve $f(x) = 0$. Suppose that $x = n + \delta$, where $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $\delta \in [0,1)$.

Note that, for $n \le x < n+1$, $\frac{d}{dx} \lfloor x \rfloor = 0$.

1. For $x \in [n, n+1)$, $f'(x) = 3x^2+3 > 0$.
2. On each interval, $x \in [n, n+1)$, f(x) is increasing.
3. $f(6) = \dfrac{8}{27}$.
4. For all $x \ge 6$, $f(x) > 0$.
5. $f(3) = -\frac{964}{27}$ and $f(3.99)=3.7875$
6. For all $x \le 3$, $f(x) < 0$.

It follows that $f(x) = 0$ implies that $3 < x < 6$.

---

$x=3+\delta$

$\qquad f(x) = \delta^3 + 9\delta^2 + 30\delta - 964/27$

$\qquad f(x) = 0 \implies x \approx 3.91403$

---

$x=4+\delta$

$\qquad f(x)= \delta^3 + 12\delta^2 + 51\delta - \dfrac{101}{27}$

$\qquad f(x) = 0 \implies x \approx 4.072117 $

---

$x=5+\delta$

$\qquad f(x) = \delta^3 + 15\delta^2 + 78\delta - 748/27$

$\qquad f(x) = 0 \implies x = \dfrac{16}{3}$

Comment: It is not always the case that $f(n)\leqslant f(n+1)$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$. I feel like steps 3-4 and 5-6 need a better justification.

Comment: @user3733558:  I said for $n \le x <n+ 1$ that $f(x)$ is increasing. This does not imply that $f(n) < f(n+1)$.

Comment: that's my point: you claim in 4. that for all $x\geq 6$, $f(x) > 0$. I simply ask, how do you know? $f(6)$ being positive is not enough.

Comment: @user3733558: I added some extra stuff to explain why

Comment: I don't see a solid argument though. If you take $g(x) = x^3 - 6x^2 + 3x - 478/27$, then you can show that $g(x) \leqslant f(x)$ for all $x$, that $g(x)$ is increasing for $x\geqslant 4$, and finally properly support your claim 4.

Comment: @user3733558: I did just that and it got deleted.

Comment: Sorry to hear, I've had some browser cache issues as well on this site. Bummer :(